# Can't print the content at a specific index in an ArrayList object

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have the following Team class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Team {

private String name;    
private int noOfTeams;

public ArrayList<Team> teamList; 

//no-arg constructor, creates the array list of default teams
Team(){
    this.teamList = new ArrayList<Team>();

    teamList.add(new Team("Brondby IF"));
    teamList.add(new Team("AaB"));
    teamList.add(new Team("Viborg FF"));
    teamList.add(new Team("Esbjerg"));
    teamList.add(new Team("FC Copenhagen"));
    teamList.add(new Team("Randers FC"));
    teamList.add(new Team("FC Midtjylland"));
    teamList.add(new Team("FC Nordsjaelland"));
    teamList.add(new Team("Odense BK"));
    teamList.add(new Team("AGF Aarhus"));
    teamList.add(new Team("FC Vestsjaelland"));
    teamList.add(new Team("Sonderjyske"));

}

//constructor using name
Team(String name){
    this.name =name;
}

    //get name of team
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

//get the size of the arrayList
public int getSize(){
    return teamList.size();
}

//get an element at a specific index i
public Team getIndex(int i){
    return teamList.get(i);
}
```

and a client (test) class where I try to print the element at the 2nd position (for example) in the `ArrayList` using the `getIndex()` method I have defined above:

```
public class TestTeam {

public static void main(String[] args){


    Team teamList = new Team();     
    System.out.print(teamList.getIndex(2));
}   
}
```

This above is giving me the position : `Team@45a1472d`. I tried using:

```
System.out.print((teamList.getIndex(2)).toString());
```

but with same result. When I debug it the value of `teamList.getIndex(2)` seems to be null. I can not see what am I doing wrong with the method in the Team class, any tip/ help is appreciated.

Comment: _"This above is giving me the position : Team@45a1472d"_ You need to override the `toString()` method herited from the object class in your `Team` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ovveride the `toString()`  method in  `Team` class. Otherwise it will call the [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

Right now it's printing the default implementation of `Object` class `toString()` method, which is implemted in way to give the the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

```
public class Team {

@Ovveride
public String toString() {
    //build a string for team class to print and return here.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

A  main problem is that your program structure is off: Team should not contain an `ArrayList<Team>`. That ArrayList should reside in another class, say the League or TeamList class. You're at risk of running into a StackOverflowException with your current code.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> In your suggestion should TeamList / ArrayList class be a subclass of Team? Can you be a litlle more specific about the risks if I keep it as it is now?

No, it should definitely not be a sub-class. Think of it logically: a baseball league is not a specialized type of baseball team, is it? Nope, and so your idea to sub-class does not satisfy the "is-a" rule for subclassing. It should be its own class with its own non-static methods and fields.

Comment: I am not very experienced with OOP, I initially had the list of team in a separate class, but then changed it, just to have all Team  related elements in Team. In your suggestion should TeamList / ArrayList class be a subclass of Team? Can you be a litlle more specific about the risks if I keep it as it is now? Thanks